# Non-EU citizen working in EU state, can I marry EU national living in another EU state?

Tags: visas, europe, eu-citizens, family, weddings

My girlfriend is a UK national and currently she is living in Germany. I am not a EU national, but I can go to Holland on a work visa as I am working for a company from here in my home country.

If I go to Holland, can I marry her when she's in Germany? Going to UK is not at all an option.

Another option was to get married in my home country - but marriage visas take a long time, longer than a year in many cases from my country. So, I am not considering this option either.

Please advise. Is there any other way to achieve the same result? If the above option is possible, what things shall I keep in mind?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Unfortunately your question is regarding immigration which is off-topic for this forum please review [Help Q&A](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) for further information.

Comment: Come on guys, love is in the air, the guy is asking if he can get married while he is visiting Germany on a tourist visa! since he can enter Germany as a tourist because he holds a NL work visa. I think it is totally on-topic.

Comment: Which specific type of Dutch visa would you get?

Comment: I can get work visa to work from there.

Comment: This you wrote already but what does that mean precisely? Is it a short-term or a long-term visa? A Dutch residence permit?

Comment: @Annoyed: Does it matter? If he holds a Dutch short-term visa, long-term visa or residence permit, he has in all cases the same rights as any other EU citizen to visit Germany as a tourist.

Comment: @Annoyed Short term you meant 3 months visa I guess. This is business visa and I actually can't work with that visa. Work visa has different procedure and is long term. I was talking about long term visa.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don't know (I don't think I will be able to answer, actually, I am just asking in the hope to clarify things for everybody) but he is not asking about tourism and he is not a EU citizen… In any case, I think it's useful to be precise.

Comment: @user9223 Do you reside in the Netherlands? Will you move there? How is that visa called exactly?

Comment: One reason I am asking all this is that if you plan on getting a long-term visa for the Netherlands, you could see if it's possible to marry there. You would already be a resident, hence eschewing the whole immigration issue, and your girlfriend, being a UK citizen, should have no problem getting there. Once you are married, you have a EU spouse and things should get easier, no matter where you want to live (Netherlands, UK, Germany…).

Comment: One thing you should definitely keep in mind is that if you intend to move with your (future) wife to Germany, you won't be able to apply for a residence permit from within the country (except if you come from a few select countries like the US). Even if you manage to marry, you would therefore need to leave the country after marrying and wait abroad for the right visa.

Comment: But he's not asking about travelling, he's asking about getting married. We can help him with travelling to where his girlfriend is, or with her travelling to where he is, but all the paperwork, rules and regulations, laws involved are beyond our scope. If "love in the air" trumps all other site rules perhaps he should ask on stack overflow which has a vastly bigger audience and where "come on guys" arguments usually prevail d-;

Comment: @hippeitrail It's really difficult to draw a line between both aspects of the question. The visa required *always* depends on your purpose. That's why we have questions about working, job interviews, tourism, etc. We cannot really help anybody with travelling without knowing about paperwork, rules and regulations.

Comment: Yes but we're good at the travel part of the equation but not very good at the paperwork, rules, and regulations. The expat site might attract people that do have that expertise, especially if it is decided that it should also embrace immigration questions. I haven't downvoted or voted to close this question ...

Comment: Still not able to offer a full answer but a quick follow-up: German authorities might require you to be a resident to marry (which means applying for an immigration visa, which as others have noted is beyond the current scope of this website). Usually Germans need an extract from the population register of the town in which they reside (which, again, could mean you need a residence permit and not only a Schengen visa or long-term visa from another country) but the relevant websites are quite elusive about what foreigners need so you should really contact the town administration.

Comment: The process could also be longer than the length of time you are allowed to stay in Germany as a visitor (even with a Dutch residence permit, you are not allowed to take up residence in Germany, only to visit for a limited period of time!) so you might need to go back to your home country or at least to the Netherlands at some point. OTOH, I asked around and it seems that since your wife-to-be is a EU citizen, some visa requirements would not apply to you (most importantly, you shouldn't need to prove you know some German). There should be a EU directive about that (sorry no reference).

Comment: Why does this have close votes?? OP is staying in his home country! He doesn't even say that he wishes to move to Europe! He just wants to get married. What's the deal with close voting?

Answer (score 4):

I can only answer about marriage in Germany. One condition is that one of the two is a resident of the area of the Standesamt (registration office) where the marriage is conducted, so you would have to get married where she lives in Germany (a man living at town A and a woman living in town B could choose to get married in A or B, but not elsewhere). The other main condition is that the marriage must meet all legal requirements according to German laws and according to the laws where both are citizens, that is UK law and your country's law.

Your wife to be can contact the Standesamt where she lives, and they can obviously tell her the legal requirements according to German law, and requirements according to UK law, and most likely (unless you come from a very obscure country) they will know the legal requirements of your home country. If things need to be done in your home country, a consulate or embassy will count as your "home country". For example, she will have to visit a UK consulate in Germany because the wedding has to be publicly announced in the UK for 14 days. The Standesamt will also know what you need to do to make the marriage recognised in your home country, and what consequences there will be on citizenship.

Any papers you need to provide will have to be translated to German by a qualified translator.